# How to make a shared DeepLink clickable with Kotlin in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, share, deep-linking, offline

I am trying to implement a sharing function to share a local json file to another user with the same app via WhatsApp, email, messenger etc.

From my understanding the different link types `App-Link` and `Deep-Link` have the main difference, that App links are connected with a web domain and thus are clickable by default. DeepLinks however are for navigating to a specific content in an app without the use of a web domain, which I understand as that they work for offline stored content, for example for images or in my case a data class that's converted to json.

May Application works offline and I don't have the need for a domain anywhere else so I think that I need to use a `Deep-Link` for my use case.

So far I implemented the share Intent and the necessary function to collect the shared content *and it works*, **BUT** ***my shared Deep-Link is not clickable***, neither on WhatsApp, Gmail, Notes or anywhere else. Instead the user has to copy the shared text, then choose share and select my App, which is really inconvenient.

My AndroidManifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="myscheme"
            android:host="myhost" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

```
fun share(content: SomeDataClass, context: Context) {
    val gson = Gson()
    val jsonData = gson.toJson(content)

    val deepLink = Uri.Builder()
        .scheme("myscheme")
        .authority("myhost")
        .appendQueryParameter("data", jsonData) // Include the data as a query parameter
        .build()

    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject")
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, deepLink)
    intent.type = "text/plain"

    val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share your content...")

    startActivity(context, shareIntent, null)
}
```

I tried using some html `val htmlContent = "<a href=\"$deepLink\">name</a>"` but every messenger seems to have problems recognising the content of the link, as sharing this shows a toast "Cannot send empty Text" and aborts the share intent. Tested on Android 7, 8 and 13.

I cannot believe that this is the expected behaviour for sharing local content, as it is quite inconvenient for the user. Because the sent text is a Deep**LINK** I would think that as a **Link** it should be clickable, right? But how?

I tried to find a solution for this for a week now but I do not find any new information on this topic, can anyone with experiences for such use cases help me? Is it even possible to achieve that behaviour?